# Highcharts live update via EventSource not working

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this example code where I wanna update my chart every time on event "onmessage" but it doesnt update the chart.
A console.log() shows me that the callback is executed with the right values but nothing appears in the chart.

HTML part

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

JavaScript Part:
setting the options....

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            Highcharts.setOptions({
                global: {
                    useUTC: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        turboThreshold: 0 // 0 to disable https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.turboThreshold
                    }
                }
            });
```

creating the chart with a timespan of 1 hour:

```
            var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'spline',
                    animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                    marginRight: 10
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Live Test.sensor.val'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickPixelInterval: 150
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Value'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                          Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                          Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                exporting: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Test.sensor.val',
                    data: (function () {
                        // generate an array of random data
                        var data = [],
                          time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                          i;

                        for (i = -60 * 60; i <= 0; i += 1) { //defines the visible timespan on x axis
                            data.push({
                                x: time + i * 1000,
                                y: null
                            });
                        }
                        return data;
                    }())
                }]
            });
```

here I am hoping to get the values into the chart but it is not working...
Just the console.log() shows me the values but nothing is updated in the chart.

```
            var ev = new EventSource("/incommingEventHandler.ashx");
            ev.onmessage = function (e) {
                var dat = e.data;
                var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                y = dat;
                console.log(x, y); //showing values correctly but no update on chart? Why?
                chart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, true);
            };
        });
```

Thanks Dieter

Comment: Seeing as you are shifting points when you add them, are the new points you add different from your previous points? This is very hard to troubleshoot without being able to see how a sample of your data looks like, and knowing what is returned in `e.data`.

Comment: e.data is containing float like 2.344 etc ==> meassurement values of temperature.

Comment: Do `e.data` return a float ? if not use `var dat = parseFloat(e.data)` .Just after `console.log(x, y);` add `console.log(chart)` to be sure the chart is found.

Answer (score 0):

it was my fault.
Server sent events seams to be transmitted as strings.
Therefore my value from e.data is from type string.

I casted it via parseFloat(y) and everything is working fine now.

Comment: Just my comment ^^